# Preventing Wine from disabling my second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, wine, games

I am trying to play League of Legends via Wine which I managed to get a stable 60 fps from, there are just a couple problems I am encountering.

Whenever the actual game starts, Wine disables my second monitor. I can easily turn it back on without any problems using:

`xrandr -s 0`

Option 0 being the 3360x1050 option.

I have found a couple of ways to solve this but all seem to have drawbacks.

- If I switch from TwinView to Xinerama Wine doesn't disable my second monitor but then I only get about 12 FPS. I read that this is because Xinerama disables graphics acceleration.
- If I set Wine up to run a virtual desktop this works except this means I cannot run in fullscreen. Perhaps there's a way to make the virtual desktop fullscreen by default? I can set the resolution to 1680x1050 but I will still have the gnome-panel bars appear at the top and bottom.

I wonder perhaps if there is a way for me to remove the 1680x1050 option from `xrandr` and only have the 3360x1050 option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run things in a Desktop mode. It's essentially a window that Wine is constrained to. You can do this on an application-by-application basis or you can do it for everything.

The nice thing about both approaches is that if the resolution is equal to the resolution of a screen, it's displayed in fullscreen mode (without decorations, above panels, etc) so it appears to take over a whole screen, without bodging around the actual display settings.

### Just one application

Change your launcher to something like this:

```
wine explorer /desktop=LIMBO,1920x1200 "C:\Program Files\LIMBO\LIMBO.exe"
```

In the `/desktop=LIMBO,1920x1200` part, `LIMBO` is just the title for the window and `1920x1200` is the resolution.

### For everything in a Wine prefix

Run `winecfg` and go to the Graphics tab. Check the "Emulate a virtual desktop" and enter a resolution. From now on when you run something in that prefix, it'll load in a virtual desktop.

---

I personally use a mix. My default Wine prefix doesn't force it all the time but there are some single applications I run through `explorer /desktop...`. Other things (like PlayOnLinux bottles) are just easier to configure with `winecfg`.

Comment: Okay, I just tried adding the `explorer /desktop` extension to my launcher and this works. It wasn't working earlier when I used `winecfg` to do the same thing. (The panels weren't being hidden). Hurrah, I can finally play LoL on Ubuntu :) Thank you. (I can't mark you as an answer as I don't have enough rep :C )